# Integrating factor method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I'm confused with this particular question, so could someone please explain how to go about doing a question such as this one?

I want to place the following equation in a form suitable for using the integrating factor method:
$$(x-3)\frac{dy}{dx}-y=(x-3)^2$$

I want to solve the above differential equation given $y=10$ when $x=5$.

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: is it $$\frac{dy}{dx}-y=(x-3)^2$$?

Comment: sorry about that and its $$(x-3)\frac{dy}{dx}-y=(3-x)^2$$

Comment: the thing is i dont understand how to go about doing such question in general i missed the class due to work (PT student) and i was hoping i would be given an explanation on how to go about doing the questions i asked i.e put it in the form and solve

Answer (score 1):

$$(x-3)\frac{dy}{dx}-y=(x-3)^2$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{x-3}~ \frac{dy}{dx} ~-~\frac{y}{(x-3)^2}~=~1\qquad \tag1$$
$$\implies \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y}{x-3}\right)~=~1$$
Integrating, $$\frac{y}{x-3}=~x~+~c\qquad \text{where $~c~$ is constant.}$$
$$\implies y~=~(x-3)(x+c)\qquad \text{where $~c~$ is constant.}$$

---

**Using the integrating factor method:**

$$(x-3)\frac{dy}{dx}-y=(x-3)^2$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx} ~-~\frac{y}{(x-3)}~=~{x-3}~\quad \tag2$$
which is of the form $$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)\qquad \text{where $~P(x)~=~-~\frac{1}{(x-3)}~$ and $~Q(x)~=~{x-3}~$}$$
Integrating factor (I.F.) is $$e^{\int P(x)~dx}=e^{-\int \frac{1}{(x-3)}~dx}=\frac{1}{(x-3)}$$
Multiplying both side of $(2)$ by I.F. we have $$ \frac{1}{x-3}~ \frac{dy}{dx} ~-~\frac{y}{(x-3)^2}~=~1$$which is exactly the equation $(1)$. So by this method the solution is $$y~=~(x-3)(x+c)\qquad \text{where $~c~$ is constant.}$$

Now given that when $~x=5~$, $~y=10~$ so we have $~10=2(5+c)\implies c=0$

Hence the particular solution is $$y=x(x-3)$$

Answer (score 0):

for the particular solution make the ansatz $$y_p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$ with $a,b,c$ real numbers.
the solution is given by $$y=x(x-3)+C(x-3)$$